# Showing SelectedItem Details to its side

Tags: c#, wpf, position, listviewitem

I've a ListView bound to an `ObservableCollection<Foo>`. On selecting a ListViewItem I display the details of the SelectedItem(Foo members) in a container. It works fine.

Now all I want is to display the details just next to the SelectedItem. ie, If I select the fourth ListViewItem then the Container's Top should be the same as the ListViewItem's Top. How would I sync their position provided it should create any problem even while scrolling the List.

P.S: Scrollbars are hidden

**This question is not yet resolved. Can anybody help?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Answer**

Does the detail need to be in a separate container?  I may be misunderstanding your example, but I would have thought you could achieve what you wanted by adding the details section to the item template for your list items and then hiding/showing it based on the IsSelected flag:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <ContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Right" Name="DetailsControl" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DetailsTemplate}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </DockPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (ListViewItem.IsSelected), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="DetailsControl" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Even if you aren't after exactly this behaviour, I imagine you could get close to what you want by replacing the ContentControl from the example with something else (e.g. a Popup)

---

**Edit in response to comments**

The example below will place a `Popup` to the right hand side of the `ListView` that is visible only for the selected item:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />

                <Popup Placement="Right"
                        PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"
                        IsOpen="{Binding (ListViewItem.IsSelected), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}">

                    <Border Background="Black" Padding="3">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </Border>
                </Popup>

            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This uses the `Placement` attribute to specify that the `Popup` should appear to the right of the target element, and binds the `PlacementTarget` property to the first ancestor of type `ListViewItem` (i.e. the parent container).

This causes an appearance like the example below:

[image: working example]

Comment: @Steve Greatrex: This will increase the height of ListViewItem also, when I select it. That is why I put the details in another container outside the ListView.

Comment: In that case, could you put the extra content in a Popup, and set the Popup.IsOpen property in the DataTrigger?  That way you can position the Popup more or less wherever you want relative to the ListViewItem without affecting the height.  The only downside of this is that it might obscure other content...

Comment: @Steve Greatrex: How would I get the bounds of selected item so that i could display the popup to its right? P.S: I don't want it to be displayed at MousePoint/Mouse

Comment: @Veer: you don't need to get the bounds of the selected item; you just need to set the Placement and PlacementTarget properties appropriately through bindings to the selected item

Comment: @Steve: How would I set PlacementTarget to the selectedItem in the ListView. Some xaml code would help.

Comment: @Steve: Got one more issue now:( Have raised it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348592/unable-to-access-viewmodel-properties-from-inside-listvew-resources.