# Unable to access viewmodel properties from inside Listvew.Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm trying to bind the SelectedItem to a View. But the view is not able to access the viewmodel when it is inside the Resources block.
When the datacontext is re-assigned to the children, the binding works for textblocks but not for UserControl (NoteView)

Am I missing any Binding?

PFB revised(entire) code and inline comments.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Konduva.View.NoteSearchView"
<!-- other namespaces here -->
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
DataContext="{Binding NoteSearch, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}"               
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNote}">
        <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:NoteViewModel}">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        <Popup Placement="Right"
                           PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"
                           IsOpen="{Binding (ListViewItem.IsSelected), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"
                           DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}">
                            <StackPanel>
  <!-- This is working -->      <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedNote.Title}" />
  <!-- This is not working -->  <v:NoteView DataContext="{Binding SelectedNote}" />                                
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Popup>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.Resources>            
        </ListView>  
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

NoteView:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" /> // This Text is not displayed
</Grid>
```

Comment: are you refering to the bindings in the popup as not working?

Comment: @pivotnig: No. The one in the NoteView. Check my inline comments.

Comment: Two quick thoughts: would you happen to be overriding the datacontext in the usercontrol, it happened to me once and spent some time finding my mistake :) Also, you probably already checked that, but do you see any binding error in the visual studio output window?

Comment: Hi Alex! I didn't override my datacontext. It works if I use the NoteView outside my ListView. No, I don't see any binding error either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 3**
Since you're using MvvmLight: in NoteView, try changing

```
DataContext="{Binding Note, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

to

```
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="UserControl">
        <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding Note, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```

**Update 2**

Encountered a similar problem a few minutes ago which I didn't fully understand so I'll throw in the same solution here to see if it helps. What happends if you change it to this?

```
<v:NoteView DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Popup}},
                                  Path=DataContext.SelectedNote}"/>
```

**Update**

I'm unable to reproduce this. Try adding this in your NoteView constructor. Do you reach DataContextChangedHandler when you change the selection in the ListView?

```
public NoteView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = 
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(UserControl.DataContextProperty, 
                                                  typeof(UserControl));
    if (dpd != null)
    {
        dpd.AddValueChanged(this, new EventHandler(DataContextChangedHandler));
    }
}
void DataContextChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("DataContext Changed: " + DataContext);
}
```

**First answer**

Your DockPanel will get the NoteViewModel as a DataContext and not the ListView and since this DataContext is inherited by all Childs every child will end up with a NoteViewModel as DataContext. To use the ListView as a DataContext for the Popup you can do this. I'm not sure what the DataContext Binding for the StackPanel does though, so I might be missing something here..

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:NoteViewModel}">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        <Popup Placement="Right" 
               PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}" 
               IsOpen="{Binding (ListViewItem.IsSelected), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"
               DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedNote.Title}" />
                <StackPanel>
                    <v:NoteView DataContext="{Binding SelectedNote}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Popup>
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi Meleak, The solution given by you didn't work. Unfortunately the UserControl(NoteView) is not able to consume the SelectedNote. I've edited my question. Please check my inline comments.

Comment: @Veer: Have you had any progress on your problem? Did you try out my way of trouble shooting?

Comment: @Meleak: The DataContextChangedHandler is not reached when selection changed. It works when the NoteView is outside the listview.

Comment: @Veer: Updated my answer. Encountered a similar problem just a few minutes ago and this worked

Comment: @Meleak: Fruitless:( Are you able to reproduce the issue? Do you need more code?

Comment: @Veer: I'm not able to reproduce it no.. More code would help yes. Anyway to reproduce this problem in a small scale somehow?

Comment: @Meleak: Can you come in google talk? My id is lazyguy2010@gmail.com.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inserting a NoteView directly and binding the DataContext, use a ContentPresenter:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedNote}>
    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <v:NoteView />
       </DataTemplate>
   </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Comment: Hey Steve, gr8 2 c u again. I tried this with <DataTemplate> surrounding the view. But it didn't work.

Comment: @veer i'm not at a computer just now so I can't test this, but you may need to use a ContentControl instead of a ContentPresenter

Comment: It didn't work. <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedNote}"> <ContentControl.ContentTemplate> <DataTemplate> <v:NoteView /> </DataTemplate>
                                    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                                </ContentControl>

Comment: Forget the usercontrol. I'm not able to access SelectedNote even within a TextBlock (check my code). I'm able to access only if I set the DataContext in the stackpanel.